# Conditional formatting for meetings outside normal working hours in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to get meetings that start before 10:00 AM highlighted in red. I've tried to use the Conditional Formatting feature; in the advanced tab I selected the "Start" field and "on or before" condition, but when I type a time "10:00 AM" in the value field it just highlights everything. Any idea how this can be done?

For bonus points, I'd also love to find a way to forward those meetings on to my personal e-mail/calendar.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?